# Imported SL rectangular mesh doesn't allow edge loops after decimation modifier

Tags: modifiers

OBJECTIVE : Import a rectangular box (Panel) from Second Life and use edge loops to cut a doorway/window through the panel, in Blender..

HISTORY : I have a rectangular box that I imported from Second Life.  I've opened it and it has 9 quads per face (18 triangles).  I decimated the rectangular box using DECIMATE modifier (using planar), and it resulted with each face as a single quad.  I was unable to create an edge loop around the rectangle, ONLY able to put an edge on one face...  So, I used SOLIDIFY modifier.  That failed.  I tried SOLIDIFY again from scratch and used 1.0 thickness, which seemingly allows me to create an edge loop around the object..

2 Problems.

I.  After placing 3 edge loops for a doorway, I'm unable to select individual faces without often selecting an adjacent face, too.

II. When I delete faces, nothing deletes.  The object is intact, always.  After continual delete operations, some faces from the new edge loops disappear, seemingly at random, without any obvious relation to what I'm trying to delete.

KEY INFORMATION :

A. If Solidify is NOT set to 1.0 thickness, I can see the faces having 3d thickness of their own, not meeting to the center - and when this happens the edge loops go around the geometry of the face and not the object - which signifies that the initial edge loop problem has not been solved with solidify at 1.0 thickness, either....

---- This is what I believe causes the issue in the first place with failed edge loops on this simple model.  I believe the edges have some kind of geometry that forces edge loops to wrap around the face, INSTEAD of around the box..

B. SOLIDIFY may be falsely solving the edge loop problem, if the edge loops are STILL going around the geometry of a single face, at the thickness of the object itself.......

CONCLUSION : I have an issue with not being able to use edge loops around a simple rectangular mesh geometry to delete geometry for creating a doorway/window, because the edge loops apply only to a single face and solidify is likely not the solution because of the multiple faces being accounted for..

Due to the simple box geometry, I'm not sure why I would have difficulty with these steps on this model.  It's only a box (rectangular and flat).  Nothing is responding the way it should, and I've tried many things that have been suggested elsewhere throughout the internet.  I only need to cut a door or window through it using edge loops.  This should be a very simple operation,   However on this rectangular mesh it seems IMPOSSIBLE to do.  I'm not sure what to do.

I can share a copy if that's helpful.  I'm not sure if there is something unique about this panel?  Any help would be greatly appreciated - thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

I identified and solved the problem!!  Basically, the edge loops are working fine in regards to what they are selecting.  The mesh export from Second Life differs from the traditional box on the Blender load screen.  Its faces require decimation and the make-up of the mesh isolates the faces in a fashion that's challenging for the normal process.  Solidifying at 1.0 thickness IS required.  However, what it's doing is making each face the same size in 3d space, as well as occupying the same 3d place.

To conduct successful cuts, the edge loops should be created first.  Each edge loop was placed in face select mode, with linear selected and clamp enabled.  After all required edge loops are created, you then select the face you want to delete on each side of the wall ONCE.  After each face is removed once, you are then going to select all the other object that are inside your wall...  So face select within the hollow space and you see it's the selection size of the entire object.  Lift it up out of your object.  Continue selecting the face in the hollow area until it is see through, and all the extra items are above the model.  Now - select them in face select mode and delete all faces, and then repeat this in edge select mode (to get all the edges).  Do this multiple times if needed to remove the extra stuff.  Then - the jam part of the opening can be filled in with a face.  Simple go to edge select mode and shift + Right Click 2 edges at a time in the doorway.  Then press CTRL + E and choose to make a new face.  This fills that side in around your door jam.  Due this for each face going around the hollow you created in the wall.  This closes it up and gives you the desires result!  A CLEAN doorway/window that goes through your wall, from a Second Life Collada (*.dae file) export to Blender.

**  This is the manner in which to export mesh prims from Second Life to Blender, and the edit them to cut doors, windows, and other 3d geometric openings within the object.  Also, this is a good way to decimated the mesh topology to a lower-poly without any quality loss.  Low-Poly is a huge consideration with builds.  Learning to fine-tune the manners that we design and build with this in mind streamlines a product for editing and use in a wide variety of manners.

---

One Additional Note : The SOLIDIFY modifier should only be used on components that need to be worked. If you're NOT creating a door or window using edge loops on a component, do not use the solidify modifier or it will cause issues with it. Only use the Decimate modifier for these. If you are working the component to make a door/window, use both modifiers (Decimate then Solidify). Also, be sure to select "Sharp" under decimate and make the thickness and clamp 1.0 for the solidify. And - use sharp instead of inverse for each edge loop when placing (seen on left after first 1-2 clicks) and have clamp checked off. Lastly, if having difficulty selecting a face to delete, you can zoom in to select it.

The extra stuff that's removed form the worked components can be deleted by pressing B and making a box around it, then Pressing X and choosing to delete faces or edges (this will depend if you have edge or face select enabled-switch to delete one or the other). Do this a multitude of times until all faces and edges are gone that were removed.